# Inject with different scope when using DbContext with custom resource provider

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dependency-injection, structuremap, resourceproviderfactory

In an application I have the following components (among others):

- `MyDbContext` : Entity framework data access
- `DBResourceProviderFactory` : A custom `ResourceProviderFactory` providing a custom `IResourceProvider` (called `DBResourceProvider`...)
- Other services
- StructureMap

The custom resource provider is looking resources up in the db using `MyDbContext`, injected similarly as described in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10633095/63733).

The `MyDbContext` is also used in various other services, and since it is a web application, I use StructureMaps `HttpContextScoped` method to limit the lifetime of `MyDbContext` to the lifetime of the request (see [an other SO question and its answer on this subject](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6390608/63733)):

```
x.For<MyDbContext>().HttpContextScoped();
```

However, it seems that the lifetime of an `IResourceProvider` is not limited to a single http request. Therefore, `DBResourceProvider` keeps hanging onto a `MyDbContext` reference which will be disposed after the first request.

**How can I handle this *lifetime mismatch* - have StructureMap return a transient `MyDbContext` for `IDbResourceProvider` while returning HttpContext-scoped instances to all other services?**

Do I need two different implementations to do that? A marker interface?
Or is it a bad idea to use Entity Framework to look up localized resources in the first place (performance etc.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a service that has (or needs to have) a long lifetime than (one of) its dependencies, the general solution is to use a factory to get those dependencies.

In your situation the solution might be simple. When your `DBResourceProvider` is defined in your [composition root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot.aspx) of your MVC application, it would simply succeed to use the `DependencyResolver.Current.GetService` method to get the `MyDbContext`.

When the `DBResourceProvider` service isn't part of the composition root (for instance because it contains business logic that you need to test), you could either extract that logic into its own class, to allow the service to be in the composition root, or you can inject a (singleton) factory (for instance `IDbContextFactory` or `Func<MyDbContext>`) that allows you to get the proper instance to be resolved.

Comment: Ok of course, I see, push the call to `DependencyResolver.Current.GetService` further down into the `DBResourceProvider`'s `GetObject` method instead of the DBResourceProviderFactory where it is now. I'll try by passing down a `Func<MyDbContext>`. Of course, this is still using `DependencyResolver.Current`, but there seems to be no other way.

Comment: Ok this works, thank you! Found also a relevant blog post (+ comments!) of Mark Seemann: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/01/20/EnablingDIForLazyComponents.aspx